# save is not working in cakeph when all is okay

Tags: cakephp

My code:

```
 $this->PackageCustomer->id = $customer_id;
 $data['PackageCustomer'] = array(
     'shipment' => 2,
     'comments' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['content'],
     'shipment_equipment' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['shipment_equipment'],
     'shipment_note' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['shipment_note'],
     'issue_id' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['issue_id']
     );
     pr($data); exit;
     $this->PackageCustomer->save($data['PackageCustomer']);
     //var_dump($this->PackageCustomer->invalidFields());
     //  pr($this->PackageCustomer->error);
     echo $this->PackageCustomer->getLastQuery(); exit;
```

I inspect array $data. Data is being revived properly. And  getLastQuery function is:

```
function getLastQuery() {
   $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
   $logs = $dbo->getLog();
   $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
   return $lastLog['query'];
 }
```

Which is defined in appModel. I am using cakephp 2.6.9. But last query is :COMMIT which does not make any sense. I check My model convention. It is okay. Now what is the problem in my code?

Comment: why do you consider `commit` to be an error? Please look at the whole sql log not the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
$this->PackageCustomer->id = $customer_id;
 $data['PackageCustomer'] = array(
     'shipment' => 2,
     'comments' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['content'],
     'shipment_equipment' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['shipment_equipment'],
     'shipment_note' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['shipment_note'],
     'issue_id' => $this->request->data['Ticket']['issue_id']
     );
     pr($data); exit;
     $this->loadModel('PackageCustomer');
     $this->PackageCustomer->save($data['PackageCustomer']);
     //var_dump($this->PackageCustomer->invalidFields());
     //  pr($this->PackageCustomer->error);
     echo $this->PackageCustomer->getLastQuery(); exit;
```

If the above code doesn't work I need the following answered to help further...

I need bit more information can you confirm the following:

- What is the name of the table you are trying to save to?
- What is the name of the class relating the to the table you are trying to save to?
- Are you trying to edit or create a new record in this table?